# creating new NSDictionaries programmatically

Tags: nsmutabledictionary

I want to create a set of new NSDictionaries with different names dependant upon input data. Is this possible? E.g.

for (int i = 0; i < [holidayDestination length]; i++) {
      NSMutableDictionary *[NSString stringWithFormat:@"holidayDestination%d",  i] = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      // Other code here...
  }

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, while Objective-C strives to be like Smalltalk, it's only a thin veneer over C, so you really can't do these kinds of cool "meta" tricks. What you can do instead is set up a mutable array and for each element at `i` create your mutable dictionary. Something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *holidayDestinations = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < [holidayDestination length]; i++)
{
    [holidayDestinations addObject:[NSMutableDictionary new]];
    NSMutableDictionary *working = [holidayDestinations objectAtIndex:i];
    // Add elements to "working"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yimin, that should work. I have all these data entries in core data, but I am trying to see if by having them in memory cuts down the processing time. Thanks again for your answer.